# Web-scraping with rvest - Following a link embedded in an icon and downloading file from link

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am working in R and struggling with the following task in scraping data from a webpage: the webpage has an icon which opens a pdf document if one clicks on it. I would like to:

- identify the link embedded in the icon
- download the pdf document.

As I will need to perform that task for > 100 cases, I would like to automate these 2 steps.

Now, I have identified a formula that helps me download the pdf file once the link is identified

```
download.file('https://primalbase.com/assets/PrimalbaseWP.pdf', destfile = "Whitepaper_primalbase")
```

however, I cannot get the first part to work, which tells r to jump to the link from the original page (https://icowatchlist.com/ico/primalbase). I have tried to use the Selector gadget to identify the object code and then apply the `follow_link` formula, but R reads it as an icon rather than a link:

```
follow_link('.btnGrey')
```

here is the sample URL that I am working with:

```
URL_comp <- 'https://icowatchlist.com/ico/primalbase'
page_comp <- read_html(URL_comp)
```

Can somebody help me figure out a way to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: From the site's terms of use:"Without limiting the generality of the foregoing, you agree that you will not: [...] 1.1.3 Use any robot, spider, crawler, scraper, or other automated means or interface not provided by us to access our site or to extract data; "

Comment: use their api: https://icowatchlist.com/tools/api